# Discord.py join/connect to voice channel command is not working. (in a cog)

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

in my bot I am starting to make a music bot.
However, my join command is not working no matter what I try. I get no errors.

```
@commands.command(name="join")
async def join(self, ctx):
 channel = ctx.author.voice.channel
 voice = get(self.client.voice_clients, guild=ctx.guild)

 if voice and voice.is_connected():
    await voice.move_to(channel)
 else:
    voice = await channel.connect()
```

Edit: I found the solution. I did not `pip install discord.py[voice]`